# a function to return an instance of TC[X] for a type constructor TC and type X?

Tags: scala, types

Some background code -

```
trait forall[P[_]] {
  def apply[A]: P[A]
}

// though writing this here I have half a mind to define – 
trait `for all`[P[_]] extends (Id ~> P) 
// sub^10 (like - sub sub sub...) question does `for all` have any advantages over it's simpler cousin?

trait Pi[B[_]] {
  type P[_]
  type A
  def apply(a:A): P[B[A]]
}

def instanceOf[TC[_], X] : TC[X] = { (implicit x: TC[X]) => 
  val f =
    new Pi[({type l[x] = TC[x] })#l] {
      type P[_] = ??? // maybe ..= forall[({type l[x] = Iso[X, TC[X]]})#l]
      type A = X
      def apply(x: A): P[B[A]] = ???
    }
   f(x)
}
```

Now I've had an idea, "a function to return an instance of TC[X] for a type constructor TC and type X ?"
now I've seen libraries like magpie and scalaz with a leibniz equality and I'm wondering is something like that necessary? something like a type iso?

```
trait Iso[A, B] {
  def to(x: A): B
  def from(x: B): A
}
```

I feel like I'm close to something like the answer but I'm over thinking it dragging too much machinery in? Anyway

how to do it?